# Put a list inside Navigation View - Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to insert a list in a navigation view after click on a button, but didnt show anything, i put a button to test and the button appeared but the list didn't.

here is the code: http://snipt.org/Bzfe0

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this line: `view.add`

should be `view.push`

`push` is the proper way to push new view into a navigation controller, not `add`

**Update: I have just looked at your fiddle, let's add these 2 lines to your Main.js**

```
xtype: 'container',
layout: 'vbox'
```

Explanation:

- You must specify the `xtype` of the item which will be added, in this case, `container` is the best choice. If not, the framework won't understand it as a sencha component and treat as normal Javascript objects, which lack a lot of initializers.
- The layout of your new item must be `vbox` because you might want to display both list and button in a vertical order.

Comment: can you please post a fiddle onto this site so that I can debug? thanks https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=270#fiddle/270

thanks for this fiffle sencha anyway :)

Comment: you're welcomed. Please vote up and accept this answer to close the question for future reference, thanks